# Matching regular expression to multiple line blocks in python

Tags: python, regex, string, multiline

I'm having a bit of trouble getting a Python regex to work when matching multiple line text.

file(doc.txt):

```
<sec name="M_20_K40745170" sound_freq="mhr17:7907527-7907589" tension="SGCGSCGSCGSCGSC" s_c="0">
<feature number="5748">
<tfgt v="0.1466469683747654" y="0.0" units="sec"/>
</feature>
<mwan sound_freq="mhr17:7907527-7907589" first_name="g7tty" description="xyz">
<xyz abc="trt" id="abc"/>
<per fre="accessions" value="abc"/>
<per fre="xyz" value="abc"/>
<per fre="yy" value="abc"/>
<per fre="psc" value="abc"/>
<per fre="ttt" value="1"/>
<per fre="xyz" value="abc"/>
<per fre="Volum_5Kb" value="89.00"/>
<per fre="Volum_40Kb" value="00.00"/>
<per fre="Volum_70Kb" value="77.00"/>
</mwan>
</com>
```

I want to extract or match:

```
<sec name="M_20_K40745170" sound_freq="mhr17:7907527-7907589" tension="SGCGSCGSCGSCGSC" s_c="0">
pattern = re.compile(r'<sec name="(\D_\d\d_\w+)"\s+sound_freq="(\D\D\D\d+:\d+-\d+)"')

<per fre="Volum_5Kb" value="89.00"/>
<per fre="Volum_40Kb" value="00.00"/>
<per fre="Volum_70Kb" value="77.00"/>
pattern = re.compile(r'<sec name="(\D_\d\d_\w+)"\s+sound_freq="(\D\D\D\d+:\d+-\d+)"')
```

This worked for me by above two different pattern. 
Code I am trying to get two pattern simultaneously:

```
    import re 
    infile = open("/home/doc.txt")
    np_array_values = []
    pattern = re.compile(r'<sec name="(\D_\d\d_\w+)"\s+sound_freq="(\D\D\D\d+:\d+-\d+).*<per fre="(Volum_.*)"\s+value="(\d+.\d+)"/>"',re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)

    fn_list = infile.readlines() 
    for line in fn_list:
        search_obj = re.search(pattern, line)  
        print(search_obj)
        if search_obj:
            matching_group = search_obj.groups()
            print(matching_group)
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Out of curiosity, does the files always have that structure? The reason that I'm asking is that it resembles a tree structure quite a lot. If that is the case you could parse the documents as a tree.

Comment: Yes,I checked it is XML format. I am kind of new to python and will check how to parse this document as tree seems interesting. Thanks

Comment: Does that mean that the solution below does not solve your problem? If so you should provide more context. If it does solve your problem, you should mark it as solved so that others might find it helpful too.

Comment: It just solved my problem. Just curious how to take care if there any null/na value or absent pattern2, since file is too large. Well, it really helped me a lot. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous ways that this could be solved, here is one. I've added the information to a dictionary, where you will get a list of dictionaries as an output.

```
def parse_doc(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        pattern1 = re.compile(r'<sec name="(\D_\d\d_\w+)"\s+sound_freq="(\D\D\D\d+:\d+-\d+)"')
        pattern2 = re.compile(r'<per fre="(Volum_+\d+Kb)"+\svalue="(\d+.+)"')

        doc = []
        for i in f.readlines():
            p1 = re.match(pattern1, i)
            p2 = re.match(pattern2, i)
            line = {}
            if p1:
                line.update({'sec': p1.group(1), 'sound_freq': p1.group(2)})
            if p2:
                line.update({p2.group(1): p2.group(2)})
            if len(line)>0:
                doc.append(line)

        return doc

print(parse_doc('doc.txt'))
```

Output

```
[{'sec': 'M_20_K40745170', 'sound_freq': 'mhr17:7907527-7907589'}, {'Volum_5Kb': '89.00'}, {'Volum_40Kb': '00.00'}, {'Volum_70Kb': '77.00'}]
```

If you want to get all the values you could get it using the following:

```
def parse_doc_all(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        pattern1 = re.compile(r'(.|\w+)="([^\s]+)"')
        doc = {}
        for i in f.readlines():
            doc.update({p[0]: p[1] for p in re.findall(pattern1, i)})

        return doc

print(parse_doc_all('doc.txt'))
```

Which will give you

```
{'name': 'M_20_K40745170', 'sound_freq': 'mhr17:7907527-7907589', 'tension': 'SGCGSCGSCGSCGSC', 's_c': '0', 'number': '5748', 'v': '0.1466469683747654', 'y': '0.0', 'units': 'sec', 'first_name': 'g7tty', 'description': 'xyz', 'abc': 'trt', 'id': 'abc', 'fre': 'Volum_70Kb', 'value': '77.00'}
```